# Long running task with Task.Run

Tags: c#, task

I am running an infinite loop of updates using Task.Run. This is the code:

```
  Task.Run( async () => {
   
    while(true){
      Thread.Sleep(10000);
      checkForUpdates();
    }
  });
```

In the old days, I used to write special code for long running tasks. Does the duration of of a task execution matter with Task.Run? Is there a timeout built in?

Comment: Don't use `Thread.Sleep` in async code. Use `Task.Delay` instead.

Comment: _Does the duration of of a task execution matter with Task.Run? Is there a timeout built in?_ No, but you should probably be awaiting the `Task` that it returns. Or holding a reference that can be awaited later.

Comment: If you use `TaskFactory.StartNew` you can pass a `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` which will ensure a new thread is created to run the task instead of taking a thread from the threadpool. However if most of what your long running task does is waiting for the next loop use `await Task.Delay` and you should be fine like this. That said imo a timer or an obeservable that emits with set interval is better suited for your needs

Comment: Please clarify your problem. What does `checkForUpdates()` do? Can you benefit from a producer-consumer pattern? Or perhaps TPL dataflow? Maybe Rx could help you?

Answer (score 3):

No ! there is no built-in timeout for `Task.Run()`. That means it will continue running until you manually cancel it. And you can implement that by doing something like this.

```
int timeout = 1000;
var task = SomeOperationAsync(cancellationToken);
if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout, cancellationToken)) == task)
{
    // Task completed within timeout.
    // Consider that the task may have faulted or been canceled.
    // We re-await the task so that any exceptions/cancellation is rethrown.
    await task;

}
else
{
    // timeout/cancellation logic
}
```

you can checkout this blog for more understanding [Crafting a task time-out](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/crafting-a-task-timeoutafter-method/)